# minified bundle JS and external libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I want to reduce the HTTP request on my website as much as possible.

Is it ok to minify all the JS in one big minified file, including external libraries such as jQuery?

Comment: The only reason why you'd want to pack jQuery together with your code (instead of using the CDN) is to use the Closure Compiler to eliminate unused code from jQuery, resulting in a much smaller footprint.  If you're not using the Closure Compiler, I see no reason for you not to load jQuery separately from the CDN instead.  In addition to it being very likely cached by browsers (thus saving a download), your code will download faster because both downloads can happen simultaneously, whilst if you pack it with your code it is essentially sequential download from one source.

Comment: A word of caution for those that do go this route: minifying libraries together can have side effects.  I ran into a situation today in which a referenced library wasn't `strict mode` compatible.  This caused issues when it was combined with other libraries that included `'use strict';` declarations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes; this is perfectly fine, and common practice.

However, you may prefer to load jQuery from Google's CDN instead of including it in the bundle.
This saves time for people who already have Google's jQuery in their cache.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers here that this is fine but would add these considerations:

- As SLaks mentions, I do think it is preferable to use the google CDN for jquery. Jquery is about 60k and I feel confident that most have this cached on their browsers from google. If you use this CDN, a large portion of your users will not need to download this at all. Plus, if you are not serving from a CDN youself, you get the added benefit of a CDN.
- I'm assuming that you are planning to load this single JS, from the head. That's generally a bad idea. Javascript in the head will block the loading of the body. You want to limit the javascript in the Head to the minimal amount needed that other scripts in your page may be dependent upon. This often includes Jquery. So even if it means an extra request, I strongly believe it is better to have one script at the top with the script that contains dependencies for rendering your body and then a second, larger script at the end that contains everything else. Or even better a script at the end that creates a dynamically created script tag at the top that loads the rest of your JS asynchronously.

Here is an example of that end of page script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {

        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
        script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        script.async = true;
        script.src = 'http://mysite/js/mybigminifiedandmergedscript.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
    })();

</script>
```

- If you have much script that if not loaded at all would not interfere with the user experience of your page, I would put that in a third script that is loaded just like the script above but deferred until after document complete. This way, that script will not interfere with the "perceived" performance of the page. It loads silently with no spinning browser icon or progress bar.
- If you are using .net, I'd encourage you to use my OSS RequestReduce which minifies and merges css and javascript as well as sprites and optimizes images on the fly. All without a need for changing your code. Its available on Nuget and [RequestReduce.com](http://RequestReduce.com).

Comment: That's a lot of assumptions :)

Answer (score 1):

It's frequently done.  Just be careful that the whole dev team knows what is, and what is not, in your js file.  I can't tell you how many times I see a customer's site contain two or three or more instances of jQuery, sometimes because somebody forgot that it was already in a minified master file.

Answer (score 1):

As always - it depends on the application. While I agree with all the points above, an old fashioned engineering approach would baulk at a creating the dependency of being always connected to the internet for a little optimisation.

We have a browser application that requires jquery, jquery ui, d3js, their related css's and of course our own code to function. 
Furthermore clients need to be able to edit the source html to generate variant layouts.

So we have opted for a single simple "don't touch" line where all the magic js and css lie.
We have also opted out of a CDN approach so the html can be edited offline

We therefore have a far more robust solution at a miniscule performance price.

Ben